# Active ragdoll character stands still on the ground

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, ragdoll

I have a character which is controlled with physics stuff like `Spring Joint` and `Constant Force` (The character is active ragdoll).

I want to stick the character's legs to the ground and when it is bent left and right, the entire character doesn't move on the ground.

What is the way to achieve it ?

Currently I use `Fixed Joint` on both legs with `Constant Force` but still the character moves around when there is sudden force on upperbody.

As you can see in the gif.

[image]